# Use VSTO to copy content from PPT Shape into Placeholder and retain formatting

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I have a PPT that I need to copy the text from one or more shapes into a placeholder and then remove the original shape.

My problem is that I need to retain all formatting, but even when pasting special, I have some problems (like bullet spacing) that isn't carrying over.

When I use the method below, the bullets show up right next to the text instead of with their original spacing.

```
for (int jCurr = slide.Shapes.Count; jCurr >= 1; jCurr--)
{
    currShp = slide.Shapes[jCurr]
    if (currShp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox && textPlaceholder > 0)
    {
        currShp.TextFrame.TextRange.TrimText().Copy();
        slide.Shapes.Placeholders[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(0, 0).PasteSpecial();
        currShp.Delete();
    }
}
```

I also tried to:

```
currShp.PickUp();
```

and then:

```
slide.Shapes.Placeholders[2].Apply();
```

which corrected my bullets, but sometimes it would bold all of the text in the placeholder if part of the original was bolded.

It seems like there must be an easier way to copy and retain formatting.

Comment: When you pick up and apply formatting from text with mixed formatting, PPT applies the formatting from the first character in the source text to the entire target text string. To do what you want, you'll need to iterate through the source text range's .Runs collection; each run represents a text range whose formatting is different from the previous range. Apply that range's formatting (an attribute at a a time) to the corresponding target range.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would I start with the copy/paste (of everything) and then iterate through each run in the original, assigning the Font properties to the new content?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea exactly.